# pyspark - groupby multiple columns/count performance

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following statement that is taking hours to execute on a large dataframe (billions of records). I read that groupby is expensive and needs to be avoided .Our spark version is spark-2.0.1.

```
df.groupby("_c1","_c2","_c3","_c4","_c5").count()
window = Window.partitionBy(df['_c1']).orderBy(df['count'].desc())
df.select('*', rank().over(window).alias('rank')) \
   .filter(col('rank') = 1)
```

Is there an alternative/better way to group by multiple columns,count and get the row with the highest count for each group?

Comment: Do you wish to deduplicate the data using this `rank()`? If so you will still have duplicates on `_c1` given rank does will assign `1`  to many records if the counts tie for the aggregation. You will need to use `row_number()` to get a deterministic deduplication and there will likely still need to be tie breaking criteria of some kind. You are reducing your result set based on the result of an aggregation and there is no way to aggregate like this without grouping on something.

Comment: Does this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repartitioning the dataframe on column `"_c1"` before calling the `groupby` brought marked improvement in performance.[Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/should-i-repartition-836f7842298c)

```
df.withColumn("ids", \
                F.concat_ws("|",F.col("_c2"),F.col("_c3"),F.col("_c4"),F.col("_c5"))) \
                .select("_c1","ids")

df.repartition(F.col("_c1")).groupby("_c1","ids").count()

window = Window.partitionBy(df['_c1']).orderBy(df['count'].desc())
df.select('*', rank().over(window).alias('rank')) \
   .filter(col('rank') = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.transform(with_qtd_repeat(bulk))

def with_qtd_repeat(bulk: DataFrame)(monitor: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val bulk_hash = bulk.withColumn("hash",
        sha2(concat_ws(",", bulk.columns.map(col): _*),256))
    val qtd_repeat= bulk_hash.groupBy(col("hash"))
        .count().filter(col("count") >= 2).count
    monitor.withColumn("qtd_repeat", lit(qtd_repeat))
}
```